# Google Maps API Geolocation Text Search Place Details

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am using google maps api geolocation to get the users location via latlng, then using this location to text search for 'golf' locations around that area. Now I would like to advance from this basic map/markers view to provide place details when the user clicks on the specific map marker. The issue is when I click marker there is no response. I feel like I am one variable off but could really use some help identifying why the details & infowindo fail to appear on click?

I also saw that google is using placeID's to return details? but was unsure if that applied to the maps API detail request.

Thank you in advance for any help.

```js
function success(position) {

    var s = document.querySelector('#status');

    if (s.className == 'success') {
        // not sure why we're hitting this twice in FF, I think it's to do with a cached result coming back    
        return;
    }

    s.innerHTML = "found you!";
    s.className = 'success';

    var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
    mapcanvas.id = 'mapcanvas';
    mapcanvas.style.height = '400px';
    mapcanvas.style.width = '560px';

    document.querySelector('article').appendChild(mapcanvas);

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), myOptions);
    var service;
    var infowindow;
    var request = {
        location: latlng,
        radius: '3200',
        query: 'golf'
    };
  
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.textSearch(request, callback);

    function callback(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                //var place = results[i];
                createMarker(results[i].geometry.location);
            }
        }
    }

function createMarker(position) {

    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map
    });
 }
var request = { reference: position.reference };
    service.getDetails(request, function(details, status) {
marker.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(details.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
  });
  }
function error(msg) {
    var s = document.querySelector('#status');
    s.innerHTML = typeof msg == 'string' ? msg : "failed";
    s.className = 'fail';
}

if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
} else {
    error('not supported');
}
```

```css
html, body, #mapcanvas {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<article>
    <p>Finding your location: <span id="status">checking...</span>

    </p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two likely issues here:

```
var request = { reference: position.reference };
service.getDetails(request, function(details, status) {
```

1. Here `position` is a `LatLng`, which doesn't have a `reference` attribute.  So your `getDetails` call fails.
2. The callback function you pass to `getDetails` ignores the `status`, so you never notice any errors it reports.

Combined, this is why nothing happens.

Fix: pass the whole `PlaceResult` (i.e. `results[i]`, not `results[i].geometry.location`) to `createMarker`, so you can access both the location and the Place ID.

As an aside: using `reference` is deprecated.  Use `placeId` instead.